# Draw a curved line for mutual

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrow-curve

I would like to know please how to draw a curved line and add it to the circuit to represent the mutual, like this:

[image]

The script of the small circuit is the following:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{circuitikz}[american, line width=0.3, line cap=round, line join=round]
    \ctikzset{resistors/scale=0.6,capacitors/scale=0.6,inductors/scale=0.6} 
    \draw[dashed, black] (1.2,0) -- (1.6,0);
    \draw[short](1.6,0)to(2,0);

    \draw[dashed, black] (1.2,-1.5) -- (1.6,-1.5);
    \draw[short](1.6,-1.5)to(7.5,-1.5);
    
    \draw[R,l_=\gls{rs}] (2,0)to(3.5,0);
    \draw[L,l=\gls{ls}](3.5,0)to(5,0);
    \draw[R,l_=$R_\mathrm{p_i}$](3.5,-0.7)to(5,-0.7);
    \draw[short](3.5,0)to(3.5,-0.7);
    \draw[short](5,0)to(5,-0.7);
    \draw[short](5,0)to(7,0);       
    \draw[short] (7,0) to (7,-0.5)
    to[short] (6.5,-0.5)to[R,l_=$R_\mathrm{m_i}$] (6.5,-1.5);   
    \draw[short] (6.5,-0.5) to (7.5,-0.5)to[C,l=$C_\mathrm{m_i}$] (7.5,-1.5);
    \draw[short](6.5,0)to(7.5,0);
    \draw[dashed,black](7.5,0)to(8.1,0);
    \draw[dashed,black](7.5,-1.5)to(8.1,-1.5);
            
    \draw[short](2,0)to(2,2.5)
    to[short](3.7,2.5)to[short](3.7,3)
    to[C,l=$C_\mathrm{t_{ij}}$](5.2,3)to[short](5.2,3);
    \draw [short](3.7,2.5)to(3.7,2)
    to[R,l_=$R_\mathrm{t_{ij}}$](5.2,2)to[short](5.2,2);
    \draw[short](5.2,2)to(5.2,3);
    \draw[short](5.2,2.5)to(7.5,2.5);       
    \draw[dashed, black] (7.5,2.5) -- (8.1,2.5);
\end{circuitikz}
\caption{My circuit}
\label{fig:circuit}
 \end{figure}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning}

\begin{document}
  \begin{circuitikz}[american, line width=0.3, line cap=round, line join=round]
    \ctikzset{resistors/scale=0.6,capacitors/scale=0.6,inductors/scale=0.6} 
    \draw[dashed, black] (1.2,0) -- (1.6,0);
    \draw[short](1.6,0)to(2,0);
    
    \draw[dashed, black] (1.2,-1.5) -- (1.6,-1.5);
    \draw[short](1.6,-1.5)to(7.5,-1.5);
    
    \draw[R,l_=rs] (2,0)to(3.5,0);
    \draw[L,l=ls](3.5,0)to(5,0);
    \draw[R,l_=$R_\mathrm{p_i}$](3.5,-0.7)to(5,-0.7);
    %% line added here %%
    \draw[purple] ($(5, 0)+(0,.5)$) to [out=90, in=190] (7, 1.5) node [anchor=west] {$M$};
    %%
    \draw[short](3.5,0)to(3.5,-0.7);
    \draw[short](5,0)to(5,-0.7);
    \draw[short](5,0)to(7,0);       
    \draw[short] (7,0) to (7,-0.5)
    to[short] (6.5,-0.5)to[R,l_=$R_\mathrm{m_i}$] (6.5,-1.5);   
    \draw[short] (6.5,-0.5) to (7.5,-0.5)to[C,l=$C_\mathrm{m_i}$] (7.5,-1.5);
    \draw[short](6.5,0)to(7.5,0);
    \draw[dashed,black](7.5,0)to(8.1,0);
    \draw[dashed,black](7.5,-1.5)to(8.1,-1.5);
    
    \draw[short](2,0)to(2,2.5)
    to[short](3.7,2.5)to[short](3.7,3)
    to[C,l=$C_\mathrm{t_{ij}}$](5.2,3)to[short](5.2,3);
    \draw [short](3.7,2.5)to(3.7,2)
    to[R,l_=$R_\mathrm{t_{ij}}$](5.2,2)to[short](5.2,2);
    \draw[short](5.2,2)to(5.2,3);
    \draw[short](5.2,2.5)to(7.5,2.5);       
    \draw[dashed, black] (7.5,2.5) -- (8.1,2.5);
  \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

Feel free to play with the parameters!

Comment: Thank you so much !!